# Position from non-conserved potential

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, simulations, conservative-field

I have a non-conservative potential $U_x(x, t)$ in one dimension and that is it (there is no conserved counterpart).

Thus, I arrive at the conclusion that the kinetic energy gained in the time $\Delta t$ (in which the particle travels a distance $\Delta x$) is given by:
$$\frac{1}{2}m(\Delta v^2) = -\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}U_x \Delta x + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}U_x \Delta t \right).$$

My issue is that now, when I only wish to find $\Delta x$, I write $\Delta v = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$, which leads to a second order polynomial in terms of $\Delta x$. This, ofc, leads to two values for the position displacement. How can I determine which one of them is the one I should use? Or is there a better method given just the non-conservative potential?

*For context, I am making a code to determine the trajectory of a charged particle in an time-dependent inhomogeneous magnetic field.*

Answer (score 2):

$$(\Delta v)^2 \neq \Delta (v^2)$$

$$\Delta (v^2) = v_f^2-v_i^2=(v_i+ \Delta v)^2 - v_i^2$$

$$ \Delta (v^2) = 2v_i \Delta v_i +( \Delta v_i)^2$$

$$\Delta v^2= 2v \Delta v + \text{small} ~,~ \Delta KE = m v \Delta v$$

Comment: How is it adding energy through time? I was thinking f=ma might be better

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I wrote the power outside the delta. I tried F=ma, but then I miss the time dependence.